# printing a name of the uploaded file on the console

Tags: node.js, express

### I am just trying to print the name of the uploaded file in the console

---

**This is the structure of my file**

```
{ key: 
   { originalFilename: 'images.jpg',
     path: '/tmp/5323-h7e0e.jpg',
     headers: 
      { 'content-disposition': 'form-data; name="key"; filename="images.jpg"',
        'content-type': 'image/jpeg' },
     ws: 
      { _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        path: '/tmp/5323-h7e0e.jpg',
        fd: null,
        flags: 'w',
        mode: 438,
        start: undefined,
        pos: undefined,
        bytesWritten: 9217,
        closed: true,
        open: [Function],
        _write: [Function],
        destroy: [Function],
        close: [Function],
        destroySoon: [Function],
        pipe: [Function],
        write: [Function],
        end: [Function],
        setMaxListeners: [Function],
        emit: [Function],
        addListener: [Function],
        on: [Function],
        once: [Function],
        removeListener: [Function],
        removeAllListeners: [Function],
        listeners: [Function] },
     size: 9217,
     name: 'images.jpg' } }
```

---

**What i have tried** ::

**app.js**

```
var express=require('express');
var fs=require('fs');
var http=require('http');
var app=express();

app.set('port',process.env.PORT||7003);
app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/Details/',function(req,res){
    var path=req.files.name;
        console.log(path); 
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'),function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port'+app.get('port'));
});
```

---

**Problem** :: I am getting this `undifined` display on the console

```
Express server listening on port7003
undefined
Error: Request aborted
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/rainmelon/sample_programs/image_express/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/multiparty/index.js:93:17)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at abortIncoming (http.js:1886:11)
    at Socket.serverSocketCloseListener (http.js:1898:5)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at TCP.close (net.js:451:12)
```

---

### How to resolve this and print `image.jpg` on console ?

{Edit}

```
var express=require('express');
var fs=require('fs');
var http=require('http');

var app=express();

app.set('port',process.env.PORT||7003);
app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/Details/',function(req,res){

        var originalFilename=req.files.originalFilename;

        console.log(originalFilename);

});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'),function(){
        console.log('Express server listening on port'+app.get('port'));
});
```

**this is how i making the request :**:

[image]

***Even after the edit ... i still get the same error***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app.post('/Details/',function(req,res){
    var originalFilename = req.files.key.originalFilename;
    console.log(originalFilename); 
});
```

Comment: Use `req.files.key.originalFilename` instead of `req.files.originalFilename`

Answer (score 0):

```
req.files.forEach(function(value, key) {
  console.log(value.filename)
})
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck